# Sorting a wp_query with more than one 'orderby'?

Tags: wordpress

I'm attempting to sort a wp_query with more than one 'orderby' variable.  
My goal is to have 2 orderby variables for the following display - sort by group and then by rating...
Tutor 1 (group 1) (5 stars) 
Tutor 2 (group 1) (4 stars) 
Tutor 3 (group 2) (5 stars) 
Tutor 4 (group 2) (4 stars) 
Tutor 5 (group 2) (3 stars)

I tried a number of things, including a meta_query array but haven't been successful yet.

Here is the code:

```
if ($_GET['orderby'] == 'ownership') { 
    $query->set('post_type', 'tutor');  
    $query->set('meta_key', 'ownership');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    $query->set('meta_key', 'tutor_plugin_rating'); 
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value'); 
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
```

In a nutshell, I haven't figured out how to order by 'ownership' and then by 'tutor_plugin_rating' in the same query.  Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
    $meta_query = array(
                      array(
                        'ownership_clause' => array(
                          'key' => 'ownership',
                          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        )
                      ),
                      array(
                        'rating_clause' => array(
                          'key' => 'tutor_plugin_rating',
                          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                        )
                      )
                    );
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
$query->set('orderby', array('ownership_clause' => 'ASC', 'rating_clause' => 'DESC'));
```